# ARKit Level measuring

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I wonder how to create level measuring app with ARKit like iOS 12 Measure app does.

I am searching for the solution or idea from last 1 week. I have seen number of videos and tutorials but I didn't get idea how to do it.

What I think is  ARSceneview's `pointOfView` node which represent the camera can be used to do it like can get `eulerAngles` and do something but I am not able to figure out.

Please any help or suggestion would be appreciated. I request you to  Please Don't close this question.

Comment: Please  read [ask] and [mcve] and then [edit] your question showing the _minimum_ code that demonstrates the problem. Show the code you've written so far,

Comment: @AshleyMills Thanks for suggestion. What I did so far is just research. What I am looking  for is idea or a way to achieve this. Yes you are right that is not right question to be asked here like this way but I had no choice left sorry for that. I am completely stuck here. Hope you understand my point.

Comment: @AshleyMills I am also looking for the same solution can we use CMMotionManager or we need to really on pointOfView ?

Answer (score 0):

For getting the value to how level the phone is, I'd recommend using `self.sceneView.pointOfView?.orientation` (if you only want one of the 3 values from this SCNVector just add `.x`, `.y` or `.z` on the end).

For instance if I hold my phone perfectly upright, the value of `self.sceneView.pointOfView?.orientation.x` will be approximately 0. Likewise, holding it upside-down will give a value of around 1 or -1.

You can use these values to figure out just how level the phone is on all three axes, and convert them to degrees.

I'd recommend placing the following code in a project, and triggering it via a button, or a loop that constantly runs it, and watch how the values change. Hopefully this helps. (Note that `sceneView` is replaced by whatever the name of your ARKit SceneView is named.)

```
print(self.sceneView.pointOfView?.orientation.x)
print(self.sceneView.pointOfView?.orientation.y)
print(self.sceneView.pointOfView?.orientation.z)
```